# Yii2 create custom rest action with post params

Tags: rest, yii2

In my yii2 application i need to develop a rest action `authUser()`

```
public function actionAuthUser($username, $password)
{
    return \api\models\User::findOne(['username' => $username, 'password' => sha1($password)]);
}
```

The params should be passed with post method because they contain sensitive informations.

How can i do this? How can i set the url manager to receive with post method my params?

Thanks in advance for all the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[
    'components' => [
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                // ...
                [
                    'POST site/auth-user' => 'site/auth-user',
                ]
            ],
        ],
    ],
]
```

Or add behavior to Controller

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'auth-user' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

And in controller action

```
public function actionAuthUser()
{
    return \api\models\User::findOne(['username' => Yii::$app->request->post('username'), 'password' => sha1(Yii::$app->request->post('password'))]);
}
```